# Replacement for Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(...))

Tags: java, arrays, immutability

The continuation of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796886/defining-my-own-immutable-array-in-java).

I need to **statically** and **publicly** storage data as **arrays** but I don't want somebody to modify my data. I need only ability to read from those arrays. Therefore I think I should use something like **constant arrays** which are presented in C++.

As far as I understand `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(...))` prevents from modify the list at **run-time** but not at **compile-time**.

I've made the following class (*code is updated*). I suppose I'm **not reinventing the wheel** because I cannot have the same result using `unmodifiableList`.

```
/**
 * Emulates constant arrays from C++.
 *
 * @param <E> Type of elements. Has to be immutable type.
 */
public final class ConstArray<E> {

    /** Stores elements. */
    private final E[] storage;

    /**
     * Constructs the object.
     *
     * @param storage   Elements.
     */
    public ConstArray(final E[] storage) {
        this.storage = storage.clone();
    }

    /**
     * Returns element at {@code idx}.
     *
     * @param idx   Index of returning element.
     * @return      Element at {@code idx}.
     */
    public final E get(final int idx) {
        return storage[idx];
    }
}
```

The `size` method and some other methods are omitted.

I've tested the class and it works.

To paraphrase, if I provide my library and somebody try to modify my data, I think it's better when he/she will know immediately that it's not possible (my class doesn't have a method to modify anything) and if I used `unmodifiableList` he/she will notice only a crash of the program.

What are **advantages and disadvantages** of this class? Is there a way to **improve** this class?

#### UPD:

I decided to use @Hoopje 's advice (see answers). It's based on experience that I don't have: I'm only a Java beginner.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to protect against.  How could your data be modified at compile time?

Comment: I would strongly recommend taking a look at [`ArrayLists`'s implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java) and replace `E[]` with `Object[]`. Keep in mind that the objects returned by your `get(...)`-method are modifiable. If you do not want this, you might need to create a deep copy.

Comment: In the question you linked it's determined that the asker is reinventing the wheel. Now you created a new question to keep on reinventing it? Whatever problem you think you're solving here, it doesn't exist. I also would like to know what you mean by "doesn't prevent modifying the data at compile time".

Comment: As far as your constructor goes, it's needlessly complex.  Arrays are cloneable, so `clone()` is a much clearer way to make a verbatim copy of one.

Comment: @Kayaman I wouldn't say there's no problem with `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(...))`. I mean, both methods have existed for a long time, and classes like Guava's `ImmutableList` were written after.

Comment: "Is the magic in the constructor OK?" I guess, but you don't need any magic at all. Just allocate a `Object[]`, and do an unchecked cast in `get`. That's what `ArrayList` does.

Comment: @John Bollinger If I provide my library and somebody try to modify my data, I think it's better when he/she will know immediately that it's not possible (my class doesn't have a method to modify anything) and if I used `unmodifiableList` he/she will notice only a crash of the program. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @AndyTurner are you saying that Guava's `ImmutableList` does something not achievable with `Collections.unmodifiableList`? I've been under the impression that it's mainly about naming and some additional guavaness.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm saying that they wouldn't have bothered implementing it if `Collections.unmodifiableList` provided an equivalent or superior solution. The main advantage I'm aware of is the speed of not delegating all calls to an underlying list. I'd imagine the safety of knowing you can't hold a reference to the underlying list, and accidentally modify it, was a design advantage also.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think the unmodifiability would've been easily achieved with standard Java, but they had the opportunity to add unrelated methods like the `of()` overloads, and other such things. So the important thing about that class is not that it's an immutable list, but that it's a [Guava list](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html). Of course it's still also a Java `List` so it has to have mutators...

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, Guava does, but not in this context here, though. The issue with `Collections.unmodifiableList()` is, that it returns an immutable _view_ and doesn't protect you from getting the original list altered by something that still has the reference to it. Guavas version copies that list and prevents that. But since OP creates their own list (a view also actually) using `Array.asList(..)` it doesn't matter here much. Guavas version also has some other advantages like it doesn't actually creates another instance if you pass an immutable list already, but that doesn't matter here either.

Comment: @Tom certainly there's a difference. But if your library is returning immutable views, there is no issue of "someone changing the original" unless you write your code in that way. As for the necessity of this, I think if you document your API with "all collections returned are unmodifiable", the developer won't need too many exceptions to understand it. There's a lot of opinion basedness in this question, and not *that* much substance (in my...opinion).

Comment: @Kayaman I wouldn't call Java core "my library", but have it your way. The issue starts when someone gets a collection passed in and passes that instance to `#unmodifiableList()` for internal usage. The caller still has the reference and can modify that list (and "your" 'unmodifiable' list as well). These aren't opinions, btw. That issue exists.

Comment: @Tom He's talking about a library he's writing, not the Java core library. He's free to return immutable views, make defensive copies and so on, which prevent the behaviour you describe. You're talking about a different thing than I am, and apparently assuming I'm an idiot. Don't do that, it's not very nice. If you write broken code a lot of issues exist, that's why I don't recommend writing broken code.

Comment: @Kayaman "and apparently assuming I'm an idiot" That wasn't my intention, sry if my comments sounds like that. You and Andy were talking about differences between Javas version and Guava and I names a few differences in a more general way, not that especially in the context of this question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If "reinventing the wheel" is not disadvantage enough, I see one major disadvantage to your approach:

`Arrays.asList` and `Collections.ummodifiableList` return `List` instances, so they are integrated in the Java Collections framework. This means that you can easily use them in enhanced for loops (`for (E item : list) { }`), as streams (`list.stream()`), use all `List` methods, pass them to methods which expect `Collection` or `List` subclasses, etc.

A minor point is that your class makes a copy of the array, whereas both `Arrays.asList` and `Collections.ummodifiableList` return views of their argument, so they do not copy the array.

By the way, creating a shallow copy of an array does not require "magic": you can do

```
this.storage = storage.clone();
```

**Answer to UPD1:**

Yes, it is unfortunate that Java does not provide interfaces for collections which cannot be modified. Thus, immutable `List` instances will have, for example, an `add(E)` method which simply throws an exception. So there is no *compile-time* guarantee for immutability.

However, in the Javadoc for your method you will of course write that the returned list is immutable. And if the user of your library tests his/her software, he will very deterministically see the exception and realize that he/she made a programming error.

And believe me, the users of your library will very much hate you if you take away their possibility to use the returned list in Collection-based APIs, just for the small advantage of not having any methods that look as if they would modify it.

Comment: 1. Why reinventing the wheel? I cannot have the same result using `unmodifiableList`. It prevents from modifying only at run-time... 2. `iterable` is implementable, but I don't know about streams. `List` methods are lost, I agree. 3. I'll try `clone()`, thanks.

Comment: @SerVB 1. I answered this point in the update to my answer, at least I think that is what you meant with "prevent from modifying only at run-time". 2. It is not only implementing `Iterable`, but all the things that `Collection`s offer. You will never be able to pass instances of your class to method which expect a `Collection`, for example, because if you implement `Collection`, you must also implement `add`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've replied to the previous version of your comment. I think I understand your advice: I just have to write documentation. But what about internal code? Is there a way not to use such workaround classes (as my class) if I am not sure that I am able to remember to avoid using exceptional methods?